# Chatbot for unsupported languages

Tags: artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es, chatbot, amazon-lex, aws-chatbot

I see there are lots of chatbot engines out there. (Amazon Alexa, Dialogflow, etc..)

They work well, but there some languages which they don't support. What would be the best way to support such languages without having to wait until those bots to support them?

I am thinking of:

Client message (unsupported language)
=> translate to EN
=> chatbot engine
=> chatbot response (in EN)
=> translate to client language

Does that make sense? Are there other options out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your idea is a good one, and it makes total sense for people with no language support. However, mistranslations and misunderstandings are a big problem, and will cause a ton of confusion, which is big money for both the client and the chatbot's company. Unfortunately, the best method would be to wait it out for the next update.

Answer (score 0):

In Amazon lex u can use Googletrans library and convert lex to multilingual bot. You need to write a lambda function in a way such that it takes response detects it's locale, convert it's language to English, find answer, change answer to another locale and display the results to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Using two different cloud providers isn't a great answer. Best to keep it all in one, either AWS *OR* Google to remove complexity and keep costs down, as well as not having to skill up your development team on two different cloud providers. It will also save data transfer costs out of the cloud, whichever one you choose, and reduce round time latency.
If you choose AWS, the better answer would be to Amazon Translate, and feed the output of that out to Amazon Lex, so long as Translate supports your language. As of November 2022, Translate supports 75 of the major languages, listed here: https://aws.amazon.com/translate/faqs/